# Echo SAS macro invocation to SAS log

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Is there a system option or similar that will automatically echo macro invocations to the SAS log?  When debugging code, I would like to see in the log every macro invocation, including what parameters were passed.

So that if I submit %Test(x=1) the log will show something like:

```
MACRO INVOKED: %TEST(x=1)
```

When calling a macro in open code, this is not an issue, because the macro call is shown in the usual log.  But when outer macros call inner macros, the actual call to %inner is not shown by default.  I tried turning on MLOGIC, MPRINT, etc, but couldn't find something that would show me the macro call itself. I think what I want is an MINVOCATION option.

Below I fake an MINVOCATION option by adding /parmbuff to macro definitions, but was hoping for a way to see macro calls without mucking with the macro definition.

```
%macro test(x=0,y=0,debug=0) /parmbuff ;
  %if &debug %then %put MINVOCATION: %nrstr(%%)&sysmacroname&syspbuff ;
  data _null_ ;
    x=&x ;
    y=&y ;
    put x= y= ;
  run ;
%mend test ;

%macro outer(debug=0) /parmbuff ;
  %if &debug %then %put MINVOCATION: %nrstr(%%)&sysmacroname&syspbuff ;
  %test(x=1,debug=&debug)
  %test(x=1,y=2,debug=&debug)
%mend outer ;

options mprint mprintnest ;
%outer(debug=1)
```

Returns the desired:

```
908  options mprint mprintnest ;
909  %outer(debug=1)
MINVOCATION: %OUTER(debug=1)
MINVOCATION: %TEST(x=1,debug=1)
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   data _null_ ;
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   x=1 ;
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   y=0 ;
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   put x= y= ;
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   run ;

x=1 y=0

MINVOCATION: %TEST(x=1,y=2,debug=1)
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   data _null_ ;
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   x=1 ;
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   y=2 ;
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   put x= y= ;
MPRINT(OUTER.TEST):   run ;

x=1 y=2
```

Comment: Looks like you may have made a mistake when testing mlogic?  That's the option you need... see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks @Robert but MLOGIC isn't quite what I want because it doesn't differentiate between a parameter explicitly passed during invocation versus a call which accepts a default parameter value. I added a comment to your answer.  When testing/debugging macros, it would be nice to see the actual call.

Comment: MPRINT is the best way to see what a macro generates.  If you want to see the value of macro VARIABLES that are referenced then use the SYMBOLGEN option.

Comment: Understood, @Tom, but seeing what SAS code a macro generates (MPRINT) and seeing the values of macro variables (SYMBOLGEN) are different than seeing *how a macro was invoked*.

Comment: But what it is the PURPOSE? Why does the macro care how the value was passed?  Why do you care?

Comment: Purpose would be as a debugging tool.  Consider the situation where you have macros calling macros, and passing parameters between calls (perhaps).  Or where you use %DO loop to iterate over a list, generating a bunch of macro calls.  It would be nice to be able to see in the log, each macro invocation that was generated.  Or when someone comes with a log and says "This macro doesn't work", it would be nice to see in the log how they called the macro.  So the macro doesn't care, but I care when debugging. : )

Comment: @Tom Debugging benefit is similar to the side benefit of using %NRSTR() in call execute macro invocations.  You get to SEE the actual macro invocation that was generated, in a log line like:NOTE: Line generated by the CALL EXECUTE routine. 1    + %MyMacro(data=sashelp.class)

Comment: I would push to have it added as an enhancement to the MLOGIC option.  Since that option is already cluttering the log with the parameter values.  Or better move the display of the parameter values out of the MLOGIC option so that you can see them without seeing thousands of MLOGIC lines for every time through a %DO loop.

Comment: Agree, that's probably the best place.  I too hate all the clutter from MLOGIC, so I would like to be able to turn this on without the rest.  I think MAUTOLOCDISPLAY was a recent addition(?)  This could be more like that, just one extra line in the log every time a macro is invoked.

Comment: I still don't see how `%put _local_` or `option mlogic` doesn't give you all of the information you would possibly need in terms of debugging.  If you're debugging, hopefully you know whether or not you provided a parameter, and otherwise it gives the exact same information.

Comment: @Joe you're a fan of using proc sql select into :MacCalls to generate a list of macro invocations, right?  And then you invoke them by submitting &MacCalls.  Do you ever %PUT &MacCalls; to take a look at the list of macro invocations you generated?  This would be like that.  When something goes wrong, there's always a chance that you generated the wrong macro invocation.  The easiest way to check that is to see the macro invocation (which might be no parameters, or just one or two parameters), rather than review the full list of locals.

Comment: How many locals are you looking at??  If it's under a screen's worth, I don't see how it's much easier.  `%put _local_` would be nice on the eyes - one line per parameter, no hunting for the parameter in question.

Comment: (And, yes - I do sometimes look at the macro generated by the sql select into, but I just let it go to the output window... but can't you do the same thing with any method of generating calls?  Just have the outer macro `%put` the line generating the call (or, `put` in the data step if call executed, etc.)?

Comment: How many locals? It depends... 5? 10? Almost all with default values.  Another benefit.  MLOGIC prints lines like "MLOGIC(MYMAC):  Beginning execution."  But it prints a lot more junk.  MINVOCATION provides that same feature, adding a note to the log each time a macro is invoked.  It gives more information (parameter values passed). So I guess MINVOCATION is an enhancement to that one line from MLOGIC, which I might just leave turned on in general.  I "always" leave MPRINT on.  I don't use MLOGIC much anymore.  I don't think %PUT(%MacCall) or %PUT(%nrstr(%MacCall)) could quite do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for `option mlogic`.

Example code:

```
option mprint mlogic ;

%macro y(blah);
  %put &blah;
%mend;

%macro x();
  %y(hello);
  %put x;
%mend;
%x;
```

Gives:

```
MLOGIC(X):  Beginning execution.
MLOGIC(Y):  Beginning execution.
MLOGIC(Y):  Parameter BLAH has value hello
MLOGIC(Y):  %PUT &blah
hello
MLOGIC(Y):  Ending execution.
MPRINT(X):  ;
MLOGIC(X):  %PUT x
x
MLOGIC(X):  Ending execution.
```

You can see it tells you when the macro begins execution, which macro is executing, and also the value of any paramters passed in.

### UPDATE

Based on your clarifications, this was the closest I could find.  Basically you need to setup a libname for 'stored' macros.  When you define your macro, add the options `/ store source` to tell it to store the source code for the macro into the stored macro library:

```
libname mac "e:\temp";
option mstored sasmstore=mac;

%macro blah(something=whatever) / store source;
  %put hi;
%mend;
```

You can later retrieve the source code by using the `%copy` macro (SAS v9+).  This macro has options to write the source to a file rather than the log.  You can then read in the file and extract the default parameter values yourself.

```
%COPY blah / source;
```

Gives:

```
%macro blah(something=whatever) / store source;
%put hi;
%mend;
```

[This whitepaper](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2005/AD07_05.PDF) goes into additional details.

It's a lot of extra steps I know but that seems to be a pretty unusual request.

You may be better off rethinking your strategy.  For example, a far simpler method might simply be to define your defaults this way:

```
%macro hasDefaults(x=1,y=2);
  %local default_x default_y;
  %let default_x = 1;
  %let default_y = 2;
  %if &x ne &default_x %then %do;
    %put The default for x was changed from &default_x to &x.;
  %end;
%mend;
```

This is far from ideal as well, but you'll have to weigh up what will work better for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Robert  this is close, but not quite what I want.  I want to see the actual macro invocation.  For example, suppose your macro y had a default value for the blah parameter, i.e. was defined as %macro y(blah=hello);   I would want the log to show the difference between an invocation that accepts the default: %y() and one that explicitly passes a value: %y(blah=hello).  Point being that log shows the actual macro invocation, or if not, enough to know what parameters were passed during invocation.

Comment: Not sure how you can tell the difference between the value explicitly passed and one that is assigned because of the macro definition.  You could add the PARMBUFF option to the macro definition and examine the SYSPBUFF automatic macro variable.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, the PARMBUFF approach is what I had posted with my question.  Was hoping there might be an alternative that doesn't require changes to the macro definition.

Comment: Thanks @Robert.  Interesting approaches.  I think I'll stick with the /parmbuff approach for now, as it seems the easiest way to report the actual macro invocation.  May put in a suggestion over at communities.sas.com for a new MINVOCATION option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to update all of your macros, which it sounds like you'd have to do anyways, then what about adding:

```
%put _local_;
```

at the top of each?  At macro invocation, the only local macro variables defined will be those parameters, right?

```
%macro mymacro(x=,y=,z=);
 %put _local_;
 proc print data=sashelp.class;
 run;
%mend mymacro;

%mymacro(x=1,y=2);
```

Gives a log of:

```
08  %mymacro(x=1,y=2);
MYMACRO X 1
MYMACRO Y 2
MYMACRO Z

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.05 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

You could always also put the macro name in there:

```
%macro mymacro(x=,y=,z=);
 %put MACRO INVOKED: &sysmacroname;
 %put Parameters:;
 %put _local_;
 proc print data=sashelp.class;
 run;
%mend mymacro;

%mymacro(x=1,y=2);
```

Though it's returned as part of the `%put _local_` so it's probably extraneous.

Comment: %PUT _Local_ shows the values of all local macro variables, and yes, put at the top of macro definition will show the values of all parameters.  But it cannot differentiate between parameter values passed in the invocation, and parameter values that came in as defaults (were not passed during invocation).

Comment: Sure, but you could also add code showing those defaults.  I suppose you can't tell the difference between a default and a value equal to the default.